# Create new page without menu in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, pages

I am creating a custom WordPress plugin. I am writing all HTML by yourself. I don't use `WP_List_Table` class etc. When I create new page using `add_submenu_page` method, this page appears in menu. I don't want it. I am creating page such "Edit products". I have page "list of products", I need to add separate page on which admin will can edit particular product.

How can I create such page in my plugin without adding to menu? I tried pass NULL as `parent_slug` in `add_submenu_page` but I couldn't display page title for example...

How such pages should be created in wordpress plugin development?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add some context to the question such as _why_ you want this and what problem doing this solves for you? Is this page meant to appear in WP Admin with the menu and toolbar, but not appear in the menu? Or is the entire page including the WP UI all in your HTML? Please use the `Edit` link to add more information, it will help greatly in understanding the exact meaning of what you wrote and what you want, as well as saving time figuring out what you don't want. Without this you might get answers that answer the question, but are of no use to you, or don't make sense

Comment: I edited my post.